# How do you create multiple Spring @RestControllers each with their own thread pool?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I have a Spring RESTful service using a Tomcat web servlet that processes 2 different types of data and therefore has 2 rest controllers for each type of data. Controller #1 has the potential to perform an intensive task using lots of memory so I would like to allow up to, for instance, 10 connections on this controller. But if all 10 connections are processing on controller #1 I would also like controller #2 to have its own thread pool so it can continue processing while controller #1 is full.

The proper way to configure Tomcat is set its properties in the application.yml as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#server-properties) in the spring docs.
To set the total number of max connection one would use:

```
server.tomcat.max-connections: 10
server.tomcat.max-threads: 10
```

But, this configures the maximum number of connections/threads for the entire application, both controllers combined. I would need each controller to have its own thread pool and its own number of maximum connections. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *. Spring Boot sets up an embedded Tomcat servlet container and registers a `DispatcherServlet`. The entire Tomcat pool of threads is used to handle all requests going through the `DispatcherServlet` (or any other servlets/filters registered).

*** You should create a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` or `ExecutorService` bean for each type of data, then inject them into your `@Controller` beans appropriately and dispatch all the work to them.

```java
@Controlller
class FirstController {
    private final ExecutorService threadPool;

    public FirstController(@Qualifier("first-type-data") ExecutorService threadPool) {
        this.threadPool = threadPool;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/endpoint1")
    public CompletableFuture<Foo> handleEndpoint() {
        CompletableFuture<Foo> foo = new CompletableFuture<>();
        threadPool.submit(() -> {
            // handle all your business logic
            foo.complete(...);
        });
        return foo;
    }
}
```

The Spring MVC "user space stack" doesn't really know about connections. You can pass around the `HttpServletRequest` and maintain your own count. Once you hit a threshold, you could send back an appropriate response directly without starting any of the business logic.

Comment: But wouldn't this still accept connections even after my ```ExecutorService``` is full? I would need to reject future connections of data type #1 until a request has left the ```ExecutorService```. Would it be possible to create 2 ```DispatcherServlet```s that each have their own thread pool assigned to their own ```@RestController```?

Comment: @ChrisLaemmerhirt I don't know if you saw my edit from 15 minutes ago. Please refresh, I address the connections at the end after the code. Multiple `DispatcherServlet`s doesn't get you anything in this case.