# Limit memory or process or thread pool resources to a spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jvm, threadpool

I have Spring application with 3 Controllers, each supporting some set of use-cases, say

> SmallController - supports 1 usecase

> MediumController - supports 3 usecases

> LargeController - Supports 20 usecases

The problem is, if I end up getting extensive amount of requests for the `SmallController`, say 1000 TPS, consuming 50-60% of my resources, will it end up starving my remaining 23 usecases?
If so, is there a way to Configure my Spring applications in such a way that my surge in requests sent to the `SmallController` does not allocate it resources like memory/threads etc. beyond a certain predefined value so that the `MediumController` and `LargeController` don't begin to starve?

Basically, if I have 100 Mbs of memory and lets say 100 threadpool limit,

Is it possible to prevent the `SmallController` from exceeding 50 Mbs of memory and say 40 Threads at max while the remaining resources are guaranteed for `MediumController` and `LargeController`?

And if at all there is no already existing tool for having such controlled use of resources, can someone suggest an approach that can be explored to get started for building one?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61921122/5515060. essentially, create a threadpool per controller with different amounts of available threads. then just dispatch the requests to the thread pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to introduce "throttling" (Rate Limit).
you can have your own implementation or you can use something like Buket4j
ex: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bucket4j.

If you don't like to pollute the source code of controllers, you can do this at MVC interceptor level (cleaner solution , handle it in interceptor `preHandle` method ).

Comment: Interesting, I did consider it though, however the problem was whether this can be done with respect to a specific controller, if the requests are throttled only for a specific controller. But a bigger problem is, bucket4j may be unavailable to use. Is there a Spring or Apache or Google provided similar library?

Comment: yes, it can be done to a specific controllers, that means different rate limit for different controllers (even no rate limit for some controllers). bucket4j is a tiny library, if you are not allowed to use that for your product , I believe there can be some other libraries as well (ex: Kite)  , or you can even write your own one just after studying how these algorithms have been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Java has no concept of amount-of-memory owned by a specific thread. The memory is owned by the whole process. Running a heap analyzer on a heap dump may allow you to attribute allocations to a specific thread or thread pool but that's an offline analysis that can't be cheaply performed at runtime.

So if you want to partition resources you should start up multiple applications and set resource limits for each.

Comment: So basically I am not looking to limit my memory resources for one specific thread, but rather limit the number of threads for a specific spring controller. May be I framed the question incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the no of permits in your `SmallController` then you can try using Semaphore. Please note this is just a suggestion, you can explore options if this doesn't fit the requirement.

```
@RestController
public class SmallController{

private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(10);//no of calls allowed

@GetMapping("/someaction")
public ResponseEntity<T> action(){
  semaphore.acquire(); // this will block the request until permit is available. 
  try{ 
     //resource intensive operation
  }finally{
    semaphore.release();
  }
 // return response entity object
}
```

}

you can use`semaphore.tryAcquire()` if you want non blocking semaphore. You can check if it returns `false` then respond back saying 'resource busy'

Answer (score 1):

Memory is at the runtime level, not the controller level. Let's backup. You want to manage resources so that the app is still responsive

Doing this in the app level is going to give you head-aches even if possible. It really sounds like you want to implement an API usage plan. You can then throttle and or reject requests which overload your system to keep it responsive. Hopefully you have this available in one flavour or another (AWS APIGW, Kong etc.)

Otherwise you may want to consider deploying your app with different profiles so that controllers run on different boxes to isolate failures and keep the app responsive, or breaking it up into separate micro-services all together. This should yield better performance and give you the ability to scale out the separate parts of the app.

I know those answers assume that you have those options available, hopefully you do.